# How to use dplyr to make several simple regressions using always the same independent variable but changing the dependent one?

Tags: r, regression, dplyr

I hope this is not the simplest question. I need to make a simple regression (yes, a simple one: Y = a + bX + epsilon). My data frame is such that each column has one variable (and each column has 20 rows (observations)). The problem is that the first 10 columns are from Y1 to Y10 and the last one is the only independent variable.

So, I have to run 10 regressions, changing only the Yi (i = 1,...10). For example:

Y1 = a + bX + epsilon
Y2 = a + bX + epsilon
...
Y10 = a + bX + epsilon

(Yi and X are all vectors (20 x 1), it's really a simply exercise)

I can do it one by one, but I was thinking to do them all in one command. I am not a veteran in programming and I was thinking if dplyr could help me with this.

I am really looking for suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: Just tried to...it seems that I have done it but I am still building my reputation. Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
lapply(d1[paste0('Y',1:10)], function(y) lm(y~d1[,'X']))
```

where `d1` is the dataset